# R error: Error in UseMethod("weekdays") : no applicable method for 'weekdays' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r

Ive tried creating a day of week variable using this code:

```
weekdays1 <- c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')

fulldata$wDay <- factor((weekdays(fulldata$completed_ts) %in% weekdays1), 
                        levels=c(FALSE, TRUE), labels=c('weekend', 'weekday'))

# Error message: 
# Error in UseMethod("weekdays") : 
#   no applicable method for 'weekdays' applied to an object of class "character"
```

This issue arises only after adding a new variable (coded on SPSS) to the data file, and resolves when removing this added variable (however I need this variable in my analyses) Unsure why this is the case.
Any suggestions would be really appreciated, cheers.

```
structure(list(participant_id = c(5237430, 5237430, 5237430), 
    participant_tz = c("UTC", "Australia/Melbourne", "Australia/Melbourne"
    ), study_id = c("s4lpHqswe", "s4lpHqswe", "s4lpHqswe"), study_name = c("Social Networks and Eating Behaviours", 
    "Social Networks and Eating Behaviours", "Social Networks and Eating Behaviours"
    ), study_version = c(7, 7, 7), survey_id = c("X81ypVgkcU", 
    "X81ypVgkcU", "X81ypVgkcU"), survey_name = c("Survey 1", 
    "Survey 1", "Survey 1"), trigger = c("scheduled", "scheduled", 
    "scheduled"), export_tz = c("Australia/Melbourne", "Australia/Melbourne", 
    "Australia/Melbourne"), start_end = c(1, 1, 1), created_ts = structure(c(1587937200, 
    1587813720, 1587820680), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), scheduled_ts = structure(c(1587935280, 1587813720, 
    1587820680), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), started_ts = c("#NULL!", "43946.473611111112", "43946.554166666669"
    ), completed_ts = c(NA, 43946.4743055556, 43946.5548611111
    ), expired_ts = c("43947.901388888888", "#NULL!", "#NULL!"
    ), uploaded_ts = c("#NULL!", "43946.474305555574", "43946.554861111101"
    ), total_rt = c("NA", "56500", "33155"), rand_prob = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA"), lonely1 = c(NA, 6, 5), lonely1_rt = c(NA, 4359, 
    1377), happy = c(NA, 5, 5), happy_rt = c(NA, 1071, 963), 
    lonely2 = c(NA, 4, 3), lonely2_rt = c(NA, 979, 2319), pos_feedback_1 = c(NA, 
    1, 1), pos_feedback_2 = c(NA, 0, 0), pos_feedback_3 = c(NA, 
    0, 0), pos_feedback_4 = c(NA, 0, 0), pos_feedback_5 = c(NA, 
    0, 0), pos_feedback_rt = c(NA, 7452, 1650), neg_feedback_1 = c(NA, 
    1, 1), neg_feedback_2 = c(NA, 0, 0), neg_feedback_3 = c(NA, 
    0, 0), neg_feedback_4 = c(NA, 0, 0), neg_feedback_5 = c(NA, 
    0, 0), neg_feedback_rt = c(NA, 2695, 3267), sat1 = c(NA, 
    4, 2), sat1_rt = c(NA, 3462, 1482), sat2 = c(NA, 5, 5), sat2_rt = c(NA, 
    1330, 948), comp1 = c(NA, 5, 4), comp1_rt = c(NA, 1043, 926
    ), comp2 = c(NA, 3, 3), comp2_rt = c(NA, 1134, 851), comp3 = c(NA, 
    2, 2), comp3_rt = c(NA, 2985, 2888), comp4 = c(NA, 6, 5), 
    comp4_rt = c(NA, 2221, 1253), selfie1 = c(NA, 1, 1), selfie1_rt = c(NA, 
    2315, 1241), selfie2 = c(NA, 102, 78), selfie2_rt = c(NA, 
    1393, 1078), selfie3 = c(NA, 1, 2), selfie3_rt = c(NA, 2589, 
    883), inspo1 = c(NA, 1, 2), inspo1_rt = c(NA, 1641, 788), 
    inspo2 = c(NA, 1, 2), inspo2_rt = c(NA, 1435, 968), inspo3 = c(NA, 
    2, 2), inspo3_rt = c(NA, 3953, 883), dating1 = structure(c(NA, 
    1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), dating1_rt = c(NA, 
    2710, 1064), dating2_1 = c(NA, 0, NA), dating2_2 = c(NA, 
    1, NA), dating2_3 = c(NA, 0, NA), dating2_4 = c(NA, 0, NA
    ), dating2_5 = c(NA, 1, NA), dating2_6 = c(NA, 0, NA), dating2_7 = c(NA, 
    0, NA), dating2_rt = c(NA, 3988, NA), video = c(NA, 2, 2), 
    video_rt = c(NA, 2809, 1283), eating_1 = c(NA, 1, 0), eating_2 = c(NA, 
    0, 0), eating_3 = c(NA, 0, 0), eating_4 = c(NA, 0, 0), eating_5 = c(NA, 
    0, 0), eating_6 = c(NA, 0, 1), eating_7 = c(NA, 0, 0), eating_8 = c(NA, 
    0, 0), eating_none = c(NA, 0, 0), eating_rt = c(NA, 2226, 
    5979), dating = c(NA, 1, 2), dating_rt = c(NA, 2710, 1064
    ), partner_cat = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), partnerideal_dum = structure(c(NA, 
    1L, NA), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), partnernonideal_dum = structure(c(NA, 
    1L, NA), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), partnerboth_dum = structure(c(NA, 
    2L, NA), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), qualtrics_sample = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), start_date = structure(c(1587397597, 
    1587397597, 1587397597), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), end_date = structure(c(1587398241, 1587398241, 
    1587398241), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), status = c(0, 0, 0), ip_address = c("101.182.17.165", 
    "101.182.17.165", "101.182.17.165"), progress = c(100, 100, 
    100), duration_in_seconds = c(644, 644, 644), finished = c(1, 
    1, 1), recorded_date = structure(c(1587398242, 1587398242, 
    1587398242), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), response_id = c("R_3n97cmY4P1NXi92", "R_3n97cmY4P1NXi92", 
    "R_3n97cmY4P1NXi92"), user_language = c("EN", "EN", "EN"), 
    self_genid = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), agree_share_email = c(1, 1, 1), consent = c(1, 1, 1), 
    age = c(20, 20, 20), gender = c(2, 2, 2), gender_other = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), currentweight = c(55, 55, 
    55), currentheight = c(158, 158, 158), highestweight = c("63", 
    "63", "63"), highestheight = c("158", "158", "158"), lowestweight = c("55", 
    "55", "55"), lowestheight = c("158", "158", "158"), culture = c("southern asian", 
    "southern asian", "southern asian"), culture_other = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), student = c("yes", "yes", 
    "yes"), international_student = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), aus_international_student = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), aus_years = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), currentlive = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), language = c("English", "English", 
    "English"), language_other = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), maritalstatus = c("single", "single", "single"
    ), sexualorientation = c("heterosexual", "heterosexual", 
    "heterosexual"), sexualorientation_other = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), education = c("bachelor degree", 
    "bachelor degree", "bachelor degree"), working_full = c(0, 
    0, 0), working_part = c(0, 0, 0), working_casual = c(0, 0, 
    0), working_unemployed = c(0, 0, 0), working_student = c(1, 
    1, 1), workhours = c("0", "0", "0"), taxes = c(4, 4, 4), 
    videoconferencing = c(1, 1, 1), zoom = c(1, 1, 1), team_viewer = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), microsoft_teams = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), skype = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), webex = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), googlemeet = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), joinme = c(NA, NA, NA), whats_app = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), slack = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), houseparty = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), videoconferencing_other = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), videoconferencing_othertext = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), videoconf_time = c(2, 2, 2
    ), fooddelivery = c(2, 2, 2), uber_eats = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), deliveroo = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), menulog = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), foodora = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), door_dash = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), fooddelivery_other = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), fooddelivery_othertext = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), fooddeliverymonth = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), serviceson = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), serviceswith = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), fooddelivery_money = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), facebook = c(1, 1, 1), instagram = c(1, 
    1, 1), snapchat = c(1, 1, 1), twitter = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), tumblr = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), socialmedia_other = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), socialmedia_othertext = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), socialmediatime = c(1, 1, 
    1), socialmediaminutes_t = c("30", "30", "30"), socialmediaminutes_d = c("300", 
    "300", "300"), selfies = c(4, 4, 4), modifiedselfie = c(1, 
    1, 1), fitspiration = c(1, 1, 1), fitspirationtime = c(1, 
    1, 1), thinspiration = c(1, 1, 1), thinspirationtime = c(1, 
    1, 1), fatspiration = c(1, 1, 1), fatspirationtime = c(2, 
    2, 2), datingapp = c(1, 1, 1), tinder = c(1, 1, 1), hinge = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), grindr = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), bumble = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ok_cupid = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), her = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), offee_meets = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), happn = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), momo = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), tantan = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), datingapp_other = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), datingapp_other_t = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), datingapp_time = c("multiple times a month", 
    "multiple times a month", "multiple times a month"), matchweek = c("10", 
    "10", "10"), match_month = c("40", "40", "40"), date_love = c(1, 
    1, 1), date_sex = c(1, 1, 1), date_comm = c(1, 1, 1), date_worth = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), date_thrill = c(1, 1, 1), date_trend = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), feat_thin = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), feat_muscle = c(1, 1, 1), feat_face = c(1, 1, 1), feat_sex = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), feat_health = c(1, 1, 1), feat_intell = c(1, 
    1, 1), feat_other = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), feat_other_t = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), covid_food = c(1, 1, 1), covid_apps = c(3, 
    3, 3), covid_social = c(5, 5, 5), eatingdisorder_diagnosed = c("no", 
    "no", "no"), month_diagnosed = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), year_diagnosed = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), eatingdisorder = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), eatingdisorder_other = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), eatingdisorder_status = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), ed_age = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), ed_years = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), socio_1 = c(3, 3, 3), socio_2 = c(4, 4, 4), socio_3 = c(4, 
    4, 4), socio_4 = c(3, 3, 3), socio_5 = c(2, 2, 2), socio_6 = c(4, 
    4, 4), socio_7 = c(5, 5, 5), socio_8 = c(5, 5, 5), socio_9 = c(4, 
    4, 4), socio_10 = c(1, 1, 1), bodysat_1 = c(6, 6, 6), bodysat_2 = c(6, 
    6, 6), bodysat_3 = c(4, 4, 4), bodysat_4 = c(6, 6, 6), bodysat_5 = c(6, 
    6, 6), bodysat_6 = c(6, 6, 6), bodysat_7 = c(6, 6, 6), bodysat_8 = c(6, 
    6, 6), bodyimage_1 = c(5, 5, 5), bodayimage_2 = c(5, 5, 5
    ), bodyimage_3 = c(5, 5, 5), bodyimage_4 = c(5, 5, 5), bodayimage_5 = c(5, 
    5, 5), bodayimage_6 = c(5, 5, 5), bodyimage_7 = c(5, 5, 5
    ), bodyimage_8 = c(5, 5, 5), bodyimage_9 = c(5, 5, 5), bodyimage_10 = c(5, 
    5, 5), media_1 = c(2, 2, 2), media_2 = c(1, 1, 1), media_3 = c(3, 
    3, 3), media_4 = c(1, 1, 1), media_5 = c(2, 2, 2), media_6 = c(3, 
    3, 3), critical_1 = c(4, 4, 4), critical_2 = c(4, 4, 4), 
    critical_3 = c(4, 4, 4), critical_4 = c(3, 3, 3), critical_5 = c(4, 
    4, 4), intro_aware_1 = c(2, 2, 2), intro_aware_2 = c(3, 3, 
    3), intro_aware_3 = c(3, 3, 3), intro_aware_4 = c(3, 3, 3
    ), cesd_1 = c(2, 2, 2), cesd_2 = c(2, 2, 2), cesd_3 = c(3, 
    3, 3), cesd_4 = c(3, 3, 3), cesd_5 = c(3, 3, 3), cesd_6 = c(2, 
    2, 2), cesd_7 = c(2, 2, 2), cesd_8 = c(3, 3, 3), cesd_9 = c(3, 
    3, 3), cesd_10 = c(2, 2, 2), eat26_1 = c(1, 1, 1), eat26_2 = c(5, 
    5, 5), eat26_3 = c(1, 1, 1), eat26_4 = c(1, 1, 1), eat26_5 = c(1, 
    1, 1), eat26_6 = c(1, 1, 1), eat26_7 = c(1, 1, 1), eat26_8 = c(4, 
    4, 4), eat26_9 = c(6, 6, 6), eat26_10 = c(2, 2, 2), eat26_11 = c(1, 
    1, 1), eat26_12 = c(1, 1, 1), eat26_13 = c(5, 5, 5), eat26_14 = c(2, 
    2, 2), eat26_15 = c(5, 5, 5), eat26_16 = c(3, 3, 3), eat26_17 = c(2, 
    2, 2), eat26_18 = c(2, 2, 2), eat26_19 = c(2, 2, 2), eat26_20 = c(4, 
    4, 4), eat26_21 = c(1, 1, 1), eat26_22 = c(1, 1, 1), eat26_23 = c(2, 
    2, 2), eat26_24 = c(2, 2, 2), eat26_25 = c(1, 1, 1), eat26_26 = c(2, 
    2, 2), eat26_a = c(2, 2, 2), eat26_b = c(2, 2, 2), eat26_c = c(1, 
    1, 1), eat26_d = c(1, 1, 1), eat26_e = c(1, 1, 1), neg_urg_1 = c(2, 
    2, 2), neg_urg_2 = c(2, 2, 2), neg_urg_3 = c(2, 2, 2), neg_urg_4 = c(2, 
    2, 2), neg_urg_5 = c(3, 3, 3), neg_urg_6 = c(2, 2, 2), neg_urg_7 = c(2, 
    2, 2), neg_urg_8 = c(3, 3, 3), neg_urg_9 = c(2, 2, 2), neg_urg_10 = c(2, 
    2, 2), neg_urg_11 = c(3, 3, 3), neg_urg_12 = c(2, 2, 2), 
    dis_tol_1 = c(3, 3, 3), dis_tol_2 = c(3, 3, 3), dis_tol_3 = c(2, 
    2, 2), dis_tol_4 = c(3, 3, 3), dis_tol_5 = c(4, 4, 4), dis_tol_6 = c(4, 
    4, 4), dis_tol_7 = c(3, 3, 3), dis_tol_8 = c(4, 4, 4), dis_tol_9 = c(3, 
    3, 3), dis_tol_10 = c(2, 2, 2), dis_tol_11 = c(2, 2, 2), 
    dis_tol_12 = c(3, 3, 3), dis_tol_13 = c(4, 4, 4), dis_tol_14 = c(4, 
    4, 4), dis_tol_15 = c(3, 3, 3), lone_1 = c(3, 3, 3), lone_2 = c(2, 
    2, 2), lone_3 = c(3, 3, 3), lone_4 = c(3, 3, 3), lone_5 = c(2, 
    2, 2), lone_6 = c(3, 3, 3), lone_7 = c(2, 2, 2), lone_8 = c(3, 
    3, 3), lone_9 = c(3, 3, 3), lone_10 = c(2, 2, 2), lone_11 = c(3, 
    3, 3), lone_12 = c(2, 2, 2), lone_13 = c(3, 3, 3), lone_14 = c(3, 
    3, 3), lone_15 = c(2, 2, 2), lone_16 = c(3, 3, 3), lone_17 = c(2, 
    2, 2), lone_18 = c(3, 3, 3), lone_19 = c(3, 3, 3), lone_20 = c(3, 
    3, 3), ucla_1 = c(3, 3, 3), ucla_2 = c(3, 3, 3), ucla_3 = c(3, 
    3, 3), appear_1a = c(5, 5, 5), appear_1e = c(4, 4, 4), appear_2a = c(5, 
    5, 5), appear_2e = c(5, 5, 5), appear_3a = c(4, 4, 4), appear_3e = c(4, 
    4, 4), appear_4a = c(5, 5, 5), appear_4e = c(5, 5, 5), appear_5a = c(5, 
    5, 5), appear_5e = c(4, 4, 4), appear_6a = c(5, 5, 5), appear_6e = c(4, 
    4, 4), appear_7a = c(4, 4, 4), appear_7e = c(5, 5, 5), appear_8a = c(5, 
    5, 5), appear_8e = c(5, 5, 5), appear_9a = c(5, 5, 5), appear_9e = c(4, 
    4, 4), appear_10a = c(5, 5, 5), appear_10e = c(5, 5, 5), 
    object_1 = c(3, 3, 3), object_2 = c(1, 1, 1), object_3 = c(2, 
    2, 2), object_4 = c(4, 4, 4), object_5 = c(12, 12, 12), object_6 = c(5, 
    5, 5), object_7 = c(11, 11, 11), object_8 = c(6, 6, 6), object_9 = c(10, 
    10, 10), object_10 = c(7, 7, 7), object_11 = c(8, 8, 8), 
    object_12 = c(9, 9, 9), rrs_1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), rrs_2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), rrs_3 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), rrs_4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), rrs_5 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), rrs_6 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), rrs_7 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), rrs_8 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), rrs_9 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), rrs_10 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), negative_urgency_tot = c(34, 34, 34), smartphone = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), eat_26_total = c(48, 48, 48), eat26_oral_control = c(5, 
    5, 5), eat26_bulimia_food = c(11, 11, 11), eat26_diet = c(32, 
    32, 32), total_lone = c(49, 49, 49), total_object = c(78, 
    78, 78), rrs_total = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), total_dis_tol = c(45, 
    45, 45), total_body_sat = c(46, 46, 46), totalsocio = c(35, 
    35, 35), total_bodyimage = c(50, 50, 50), total_media = c(12, 
    12, 12), total_critical = c(19, 19, 19), total_intro_aware = c(7, 
    7, 7), intro_aware1_recoded = c(1, 1, 1), totalcesdrecoded = c(13, 
    13, 13), itro_aware_2recoded = c(2, 2, 2), intro_aware_3recoded = c(2, 
    2, 2), intro_aware4_recoded = c(2, 2, 2), cesd_1recoded = c(1, 
    1, 1), cesd_2recoded = c(1, 1, 1), cesd_3recoded = c(2, 2, 
    2), cesd_4recoded = c(2, 2, 2), cesd_5reversecoded = c(1, 
    1, 1), cesd_6recoded = c(1, 1, 1), cesd_7recoded = c(1, 1, 
    1), cesd_8reversecoded = c(1, 1, 1), cesd_9recoded = c(2, 
    2, 2), cesd_10recoded = c(1, 1, 1), recoded_eat26_q1 = c(3, 
    3, 3), recoded_eat26_q2 = c(0, 0, 0), recoded_eat26_q3 = c(3, 
    3, 3), recoded_eat26_q4 = c(3, 3, 3), recoded_eat26_q5 = c(3, 
    3, 3), recoded_eat26_q6 = c(3, 3, 3), recoded_eat26_q7 = c(3, 
    3, 3), recoded_eat26_q8 = c(0, 0, 0), recoded_eat26_q9 = c(0, 
    0, 0), recoded_eat26_q10 = c(2, 2, 2), recoded_eat26_q11 = c(3, 
    3, 3), recoded_eat26_q12 = c(3, 3, 3), recoded_eat26_q13 = c(0, 
    0, 0), recoded_eat26_q14 = c(2, 2, 2), recoded_eat26_q15 = c(0, 
    0, 0), recoded_eat26_q16 = c(1, 1, 1), recoded_eat26_q17 = c(2, 
    2, 2), recoded_eat26_q18 = c(2, 2, 2), recoded_eat26_q19 = c(2, 
    2, 2), recoded_eat26_q20 = c(0, 0, 0), recoded_eat26_q21 = c(3, 
    3, 3), recoded_eat26_q22 = c(3, 3, 3), recoded_eat26_q23 = c(2, 
    2, 2), recoded_eat26_q24 = c(2, 2, 2), recoded_eat26_q25 = c(3, 
    3, 3), recoded_eat26_q26 = c(0, 0, 0), dis_tol_6recoded = c(2, 
    2, 2), lone_1recoded = c(2, 2, 2), lone_5recoded = c(3, 3, 
    3), lone_6recoded = c(2, 2, 2), lone_9recoded = c(2, 2, 2
    ), lone_10recoded = c(3, 3, 3), lone_15recoded = c(3, 3, 
    3), lone_16recoded = c(2, 2, 2), lone_19recoded = c(2, 2, 
    2), lone_20recoded = c(2, 2, 2), lone_4recoded = c(2, 2, 
    2), neg_urg_1recoded = c(3, 3, 3), neg_urg_2recoded = c(3, 
    3, 3), neg_urg_3recoded = c(3, 3, 3), neg_urg_4recoded = c(3, 
    3, 3), neg_urg_5recoded = c(2, 2, 2), neg_urg_6recoded = c(3, 
    3, 3), neg_urg_7recoded = c(3, 3, 3), neg_urg_8recoded = c(2, 
    2, 2), neg_urg_9recoded = c(3, 3, 3), neg_urg_10recoded = c(3, 
    3, 3), neg_urg_12recoded = c(3, 3, 3), filter = c(1, 1, 1
    ), EatingSum = c(NA, 0, 1), EatingMean = c(NA, 0, 0.166666666666667
    ), appearsum = c(216, 216, 216), appearT = c(21.6, 21.6, 
    21.6), sexualorientation_col = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), sat1r = c(NA, 6, 8), happyr = c(NA, 5, 5), dating1r = c(NA, 
    2, 1), datingappr = c(2, 2, 2), currentheight_metre = c(1.58, 
    1.58, 1.58), BMI = c(22.0317256849864, 22.0317256849864, 
    22.0317256849864), employed_sum = c(0, 0, 0), employed = c(0, 
    0, 0), unemployed = c(0, 0, 0), IDorder = 1:3, Date = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    FirstDate = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), DaysElapsed = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "difftime", units = "secs")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), groups = structure(list(participant_id = 5237430, .rows = structure(list(
    1:3), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: What does `class(fulldata$completed_ts)` return? It sounds like you've not converted that column to a proper date datatype which `weekdays` expects. It's easier to help you when you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data that we can use to run and test the code.

Comment: Hi @jade, Welcome to SO! To echo MrFlick's suggestion, can you add a sample of your data? For instance, use ```dput(head(fulldata,10))``` to show the first ten rows of your data? You can paste that into questions using the "edit" option on the bottom left horizontal menu just under your question.

Comment: Probably you need `fulldata$wDay <- ifelse(weekdays(as.Date(fulldata$completed_ts)) %in% weekdays1, 'weekday', 'weekend')`

Comment: Hi @RussThomas, I've added the code you suggested, are you able to see the the first 10 rows of data?

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, class(fulldata$completed_ts) returns "character" - when I try to convert it fulldata$completed_ts <- as.Date(fulldata$completed_ts), this error message occurs: Error in as.Date.numeric(fulldata$completed_ts) : 
  'origin' must be supplied